# Retrieving the XML feeds which corresponds to the search results that the user enters in Android Application

Tags: java, android

I m supposed to implement Entertainment Guide using Android wherein the user is allowed to select a TV channel whose tv schedule should be displayed.
here, we need to retrieve the corresponding XML feed based on the user's TV channel Selection. and this XML sheet needs to be parsed, so that the corresponding details of the Channel would be displayed......

Comment: You need to parse Data from XML?

Comment: You need to accept answers that worked for you so that next time you ask questions - people don't hesitate to post answers!

Answer (score 0):

From the question I suspect that you need some help about downloading & parsing XML, right?
Get input stream :

```
URL url = new URL(address);         
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

And then parse the result stream using for example SAXParser.

More help:

- [Android dev guid](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html)
- [Sax parser code example](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/sample-saxparser-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you be a little more specific about what you are trying to achieve and what have you done so far? Please go through the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) No one will really give you the answer you are looking for unless you are specific about your problem (that's my own personal experience too!)

Regardless, depending on what format the feed is in, here are some starters for you:

[XML Parsing](http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html)

[JSON Parsing](http://activecodeline.net/simple-android-json-parsing-example-with-output-into-listactivity)

I personally used them as reference while writing my own app and they worked.